# Color transparency overlay on hover

Tags: css, colors, hover, overlay

Working on my personal site and I have images that upon hover I would like to have a dark red overlay that is somewhat transparent. So far all I can find with webkit is changing the brightness, saturation or hue of the photo.

I might add that these features only work when I designate them to tags such as "img" and they don't work with "class" or "id."

Any help would be great.

Here is my code:

**html**

```
<div>
<img src="images/amadea/book.jpg" alt="Amadea Bailey- Abstract Expressionist">
</div>
```

**css**

```
img{
    display: block;
}

img:hover{
    -webkit-filter:  grayscale(100%) brightness(51%);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an `:after` pseudo element that is absolutely positioned relative to the parent `div` elements. The pseudo element would be the same size as the parent, therefore it works for all `img` dimensions. It basically just adds a transparent overlay on `:hover`, achieving the 'filter' you're looking for. You can use any background color, customize the transparency and even add content..

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FFe2L/)

```
div {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
div:hover:after {
    content:"\A";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: @NoobEditor It's a line break or cartridge return. One of those. It's not necessarily needed, `''` would work fine.

Comment: @user3171515 : you might wanna mark this answer as accepted then...it marks the questions as completed!! :)